# Software that recommends music based on mood/bpm/genre...?

Tags: music, archiving, flac, last.fm

Are there any media players or purpose built programs, that does the same (or alike) job as **[Last.fm Boffin](http://www.lastfm.com.tr/group/Audioscrobbler+Beta/forum/30705/_/510180#f8764880)** but; with FLAC support?

Most if not all of my music archive is tagged properly with Album, Artist, Genre info but; so little of them has detailed tags like mood etc... So I'm searching for a program which can categorize my archive by getting the related detailed data from an online service and giving me more options (rather than just album artist name) on what I'd like to listen (just like Boffin but; as I said before, **with FLAC support**)...

edit: I am and have been using foobar for about 3 years now, and I'm not looking for a(nother) media-player. Please see the boffin interface, I want to have a tag cloud like that (and maybe more than that) which I can play around with and those tags shouldnt entirely rely on what I've already tagged on my music archive. Say; when I select female-vocals it should show both Rihanna and Norah Jones (no need to thank for my awesome example), and then as I select more tags, it should filter down results. (Yea, seems like there's no program like that available, I better start writing one)...

edit2: **[MusicIP Mixer](http://www.amplifiedmusicservices.com/what/downloads.php)** is another application that does a similar job. It provides similar songs to a song you have selected, in a radio-like interface/fashion. Pretty fun to use but; I'm looking something more powerful and with more user-side controls.

Comment: That's the spirit! :)

Answer (score 1):

[Foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) is capable of this if you're on Windows.

**Features:**

> - Supported audio formats: MP3, MP4, AAC, CD Audio, WMA, Vorbis, FLAC,
>     WavPack, WAV, AIFF, Musepack, Speex,
>     AU, SND... and more with additional
>     [components.](http://www.foobar2000.org/?page=Download#components)
> - [Gapless](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Gapless) playback.
> - Full unicode support.
> - Easily [customizable user interface layout](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Layout_Editing_Mode).
> - **Advanced [tagging capabilities](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000redirect:C16D48EE-39BE-4C91-9A35-441BEFA286D2)**.
> - Support for ripping Audio CDs as well as transcoding all supported
>     audio formats using the [Converter](http://www.foobar2000.org/FAQ#converting_audio_files_to_different_file_formats)
>     component.
> - Full [ReplayGain](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Replaygain) support.
> - Customizable keyboard shortcuts.
> - Open component architecture allowing third-party developers to
>     extend functionality of the player.

[Quodlibet](http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/) should suffice for most other platforms.

> Quod Libet is a GTK+-based audio
>   player written in Python, using the
>   Mutagen tagging library. It's designed
>   around the idea that you know how to
>   organize your music better than we do.
>   It lets you make playlists based on
>   regular expressions (don't worry,
>   regular searches work too). It lets
>   you display and edit any tags you want
>   in the file. And it lets you do this
>   for all the file formats it supports
>   -- Ogg Vorbis, FLAC, MP3, Musepack, and MOD.
>
> Quod Libet easily scales to libraries
>   of thousands of songs. It also
>   supports most of the features you
>   expect from a modern media player,
>   like Unicode support, multimedia keys,
>   and tag editing.

Answer (score 0):

my audio player of choice: **[Spider Player](http://spider-player.com/)** (mostly because of its unrivaled low  footprint)

> Multiformat Playback:
>
> Audio formats supported are: MP1, MP2,
>   MP3, MP4, M4A, AAC, AAC+, AC3, MPC,
>   MP+, MPP, Ogg Vorbis, **FLAC**, Ogg
>   FLAC, TTA, APE, WavPack, Speex, WAV,
>   CDDA, WMA, MID, RMI, KAR, S3M, XM,
>   MOD, IT, MO3, MTM, UMX.
>
> Unified Tag editor:
>
> Edit ID3v1, ID3v2, Vorbis, **FLAC
>   tags** and WMA metadata (support for
>   additional tag types and file formats
>   can be added via plugins).
>
> CD-Text and **FreeDB support**

or have a look at **[MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/)**:

> Play CDs and digital audio files (MP3,
>   AAC/M4A, OGG, WMA*, MPC, APE,
>   **FLAC**, WAV, etc.)
>
> Automatically lookup and tag Album Art
>   and other metadata.
>
> Tag music easily using
>   industry-standard formats. MediaMonkey
>   includes an MP3 Tag editor (an ID3 tag
>   editor supporting ID3v1 & ID3v2), AAC
>   tag editor (for M4A/M4P files), an OGG
>   tag editor (for OGG and **FLAC**
>   files), a WMA tag editor, an APE2 tag
>   editor (for APE files), and a WAV tag
>   editor.

*MediaMonkey and Spider Plarer are freeware.*

Answer (score 0):

[Foobar](http://www.foobar2000.org/) is your answer! [Songbird](http://www.getsongbird.com/features/) perhaps too!